# How to improve performance for setting up UIImage to UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, ipad, swift3

I have UITableView with UITableViewCell, which contains 6 UIImageView: 2(140x140) and 4(18x18) and some other views.

Also I use all the best practice such as:

- dequeueReusableCell;
- not blocking the main thread;
- use opaque views;
- resize images before setting to UIImageView.

But I have a problem with the iPad scrolling performance. There are 6 visible cells (iPad pro 9.7) and scrolling performance is quite awful. I discovered, that when I comment setting up images scrolling works very well, so, the problem with images. Also, I used Time Profiler and detected, that my code works fast, but system libraries during setting up images do a lot of work.

**So, is there any way to improve setting up and scrolling performance?**

```
func setImage(from string: String?, to view: UIImageView) {
        DispatchQueue(label: "com.myCompany.image-converter", qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: string ?? "", options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            if let correctImageData = imageData {
                let sourceImage = UIImage(data: correctImageData)

                let size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
                let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
                sourceImage?.draw(in: rect)
                let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    view.image = resizedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here I call setting up images from the update method in my custom UITableViewCell.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let imageConverter = ImageBase64Converter()
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerOne.player.image, to: self.leftPlayerImageView)
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerTwo.player.image, to: self.rightPlayerImageView)
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerOne.schedule.teamHome.image, to: self.leftTeamLeftPlayerImageView)
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerOne.schedule.teamAway.image, to: self.rightTeamLeftPlayerImageView)
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerTwo.schedule.teamHome.image, to: self.leftTeamRightPlayerImageView)
            imageConverter.setImage(from: contest.contestPlayerTwo.schedule.teamAway.image, to: self.rightTeamRightPlayerImageView)
        }
```

Comment: why are you using draw(in: rect), it tends to be very slow. Why not just use imageView.image = sourceImage?

Comment: I resize image before setting to UIImageView in background thread (for example, source image 1200x1200, but UIImageView 140x140). It's improvement, because without it scrolling works even slower (system would do this resizing in the main thread during setting up).

Comment: Have you tried to cache the resized images once they are generated? If you are scrolling the decompression and resizing is being done again and again for no reason.

Comment: I implemented infinity scroll feature, so user scroll down and down and all the images are different. I will implement cache later, but it's not affect current performance for new items.

Comment: а их обязательно ресайзить? если запихнуть как есть, а в imageView сделать aspect fill?

Comment: Без этого работает еще медленнее, так как то что я их уменьшаю в отдельном потоке экономит силы главному потоку, так как системные либы при присвоении картинки UIImageView делают примерно все тоже самое, и чем больше картинки, тем больше им работы по сжатию картинки.